# $rootScope object losing data across controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created an object that takes a name and an array of values.

```
//BST definition
class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor(name, arrayOfValues) {
    this.name = name;
    this.arrayOfValues = arrayOfValues;
  }
}
```

In a root-level controller, I initialize the first index in an array of them with some data:

```
$rootScope.DataStructure.binarySearchTrees[0] = new BinarySearchTree('first', [
    {
        position: new Vector2(500, 100),
        value: 23
    }, 
    {
        position: new Vector2(700, 100),
        value: 28
    }, 
    {
        position: new Vector2(900, 100),
        value: 30
    }
]);
console.log($rootScope.DataStructure.binarySearchTrees[0]);
```

And in another child controller I log this rootScope variable to the console:

```
console.log($rootScope.DataStructure.binarySearchTrees[0]);
```

The first log comes out correct, saying that the array at the first index is named 'first', has 3 values, and those values are what I expect them to be. However, in the child controller when I log that same index, it comes back saying that the second data member has one value with a key-value pair of "0 : 0".

[image: Console output of the object after creation and logged from another controller.]

I've tried replicating this in a blank project with raw Javascript and HTML and can't seem to replicate it. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how data gets passed around in Javascript? Is this an AngularJS nuance that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Should use a service to share data across various parts of the app not $rootScope

Comment: Never trust console.log output for objects, because it logs a reference and doesn't reflect object state at the moment when console was called. If you get different results in different places this means that the code is time sensitive. It's not obvious if those are same BinarySearchTree instances. As it was said, that's the abuse of $rootScope.